# Why the graph is empty

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I have written the below code in Google Colab for plotting a graph but apparently it printed the blank graph. Can someone please explain why?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

y = np.arange(0,len(x))

for i in x:
  plt.plot(i,y[i-1])
```

Result:

[image: Empty Graph Result]

Comment: Try this: plt.plot(x, y)

Comment: I know that will work but that would be a different graph from what I wanted :(

Answer (score 1):

Try `for i in x: plt.plot(i,y[i-1], '-D')` (i.e., place a Diamond symbol in every point)

[image]

and ask yourself,

1. why the diamonds have different colors? and
2. what is the meaning of, e.g., `plt.plot(2,2)`?

---

It seems that Matplotlib , when it sees `plt.plot(x, y)` with `x` and `y` both scalar values, draws a line of ZERO LENGTH from `P(x, y)` to `P(x, y)` and the only reasonable way to to have no empty graph is to add a symbol to each point in each line.

I wonder if Matplotlib draws a single Diamond for each individual, zero  length line or it's drawing TWO Diamonds, one on the first point, `P(x, y)` and another one on the final point `P(x, y)` … :-)

Comment: This works for me. and I will surely analyze the questions. Thanks for the help

Comment: @AdarshJaiswal You're welcome! Please notice that I have expanded my answer, to possibly help you to answer my questions.

Comment: @AdarshJaiswal As a side note, you can avoid the loop using `plt.plot(x_vector, y_vector, lw=0, marker="D")`

Comment: TYSM! for the help. I see your point here. Great Stuff.